# Magento 2 - how to create a new tab in admin user edit page?

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, tabs, admin-user

I want to create a new tab under `User Role` tab.
[image]

Can anyone help me on how to create those types of tab in admin panel. Please !!

Answer (score 0):

For example,

You have to create new module and layout file adminhtml_user_edit.

`Namespace/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_user_edit.xml`

```
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.user.editroles">
        <block class="Namespace\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Role\Tab\Scope" name="adminhtml.user.tab.test.scope"/>
        <action method="addTabAfter">
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">amrolepermissions.scope</argument>
            <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">adminhtml.user.tab.test.scope</argument>
            <argument name="after" xsi:type="string">roles</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Please create this block

`NameSpace/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/Role/Tab/Scope`

```
namespace yourNameSpace\yourModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Role\Tab;

    class Scope extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic implements \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface
    {
        const MODE_NONE = 0;
    
        const MODE_SITE = 1;
    
        const MODE_VIEW = 2;
    
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store
         */
        protected $_systemStore;
    
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno
         */
        private $optionList;
    
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Dependency\FieldFactory
         */
        private $fieldFactory;
    
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
            \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
            \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore,
            \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno $optionList,
            \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Dependency\FieldFactory $fieldFactory,
            array $data = []
        ) {
            $this->_systemStore = $systemStore;
            $this->optionList = $optionList;
            $this->fieldFactory = $fieldFactory;
            parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
        }
    
        /**
         * Get tab label
         *
         * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
         */
        public function getTabLabel()
        {
            return __('Advanced: Scope');
        }
    
        /**
         * Get tab title
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getTabTitle()
        {
            return $this->getTabLabel();
        }
    
        /**
         * Whether tab is available
         *
         * @return bool
         */
        public function canShowTab()
        {
            return true;
        }
    
        /**
         * Whether tab is visible
         *
         * @return bool
         */
        public function isHidden()
        {
            return false;
        }

}
```